# postgres psql suppress active code page message

Tags: windows, postgresql, console, psql

every time I run psql under windows, it prints:

```
Active code page: 1252
```

as the first line... which is obviously extremely inconvenient for any result parsing or handling.  How do I stop it doing this?

Answer (score 0):

apologies - it was a wrapper that was calling chcp - so just had to pipe that to nul.